# Value Error Invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: google-app-engine, web-applications, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore, jinja2

I'm getting the following error when I enter 1933 as the copyright_year in my form:

> File "C:\programming_google_app_engine_repo\datastore\main.py", line
>   29, in post
>       book.copyright_year = int(self.request.get('copyright_year')) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1933  1655'

Why am I getting this error?

**main.py**

```
import webapp2
import jinja2
import os

from google.appengine.ext import db

jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):          

        book_query1 = Book.all()
        shakespeare_books = book_query1.filter("author =", "William Shakespeare")

        template_values = {
            'shakespeare_books': shakespeare_books,             
        }

        template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))


class BookStore(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        book = Book()
        book.title = self.request.get('title')
        book.author = self.request.get('author')
        book.copyright_year = int(self.request.get('copyright_year'))       
        book.put()  
        self.redirect('/')      


class Book(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty()
    author = db.StringProperty()
    copyright_year = db.IntegerProperty()



app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                                ('/new_book',BookStore)], debug=True)
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <body>                      
        <form action="/new_book" method="post">         
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <div><textarea name="title" rows="1" cols="20" id="title"></textarea></div>
            <label for="author">Author</label>
            <div><textarea name="author" rows="1" cols="20" id="author"></textarea></div>
            <label for="copyright_year">Copyright Year</label>
            <div><textarea name="copyright_year" rows="1" cols="20" id="copyright_year"></textarea></div>           
            <div><input type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
        </form>

        {% for books in shakespeare_books %}                    
                <b>{{ books.title }}</b> 
                <b>{{ books.author }}</b>
                <b>{{ books.copyright_year }}</b>               
                <hr></hr>           
        {% endfor %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you are getting from the request is: `"1933 1655"`, not `"1933"` as you said.

Your web page is somehow sending the wrong date. Is there any validation code on your website, or code to format the date at all?

Comment: +1 thanks, you're right. I also have no validation code.